# How do you create a list workflow that emails users every 6 months

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm new to sharepoint 2013 workflows.  How do you create a workflow that will automatically email users every six months?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pause for duration** action in designer workflows.

**Reference**:

[Reminder Workflow Pause for Specific Duration in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/remainder-workflow-pause-for-specific-duration-in-sharepoint/).

Or you can create site workflow and schedule it to start after every 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to set up a PowerShell script in the task manager on one of the servers in the farm. This will give you the flexibility you will need as the requirements changes like "for this kind of content the reminders should be every 3 months"

Example: http://chiqnlips.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-run-sharepoint-powershell-script.html

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I ended up using powerautomate, and this task was very simple to do.  It would email every user on the list.  Lets see how it pans out when the users get slammed with the emails in January.